# Swap partition on USB for hibernation

Tags: linux, usb, swap, hibernate

I have a 128 SSD with 8GB of RAM and 8GB of SWAP. I wanted to enable hibernation and instead of repartitioning my disk (which is also a bit old) I though of trying to create a new swap file on a USB drive. Would that work? If I have, say, 7gb of RAM used and hibernate, restoring might take 2/3 minutes, which is very annoying but also fine if I have the necessity of saving my work from the previous day (my battery is not great and my device only supports s2idle, which is not good at all)

Comment: If you have already 8GB Swap why add more? While I assume USB as hibernate drive would work you might have a better experience with a swap file which you could add to your main disk without re-partitioning. Hibernate with swap file instead of partition is a bit more complicated but possible.

Comment: If you have an 8GB swap partition,  or an 8GB contiguous swap file (read `man filefrag mkswap swapon fallocate`) hibernation should use it. Check for swap fragmentation,  then attempt hibernation. If the system simply stays awake, `sudo journalctl  --since="-5 minutes"`, but if the system crashes `sudo journalctl  -b -1 -e` will give you more information. Please [edit] your question to add whatever information you get. Do not use Add Comment.

Comment: Sometimes swap gets used because I have many apps open, so it won't hibernate because there is not enough your space